# Combining multiple conditions in an if-statement

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, logic

I have an array of booleans (The number of elements can be more than what is below):

```
boolean [] values = new boolean[] { false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false };
```

And I want to get the result of combining all the values within the array with the "&&" operator. In short, I wanna do something like this:

```
return values[0] && values[1] && values[2] && values[3] .... ;
```

But with a more cleaner and automatic way (using a loop for example)

Answer (score 3):

```
static boolean and(boolean... values) {
    for (boolean value : values) {
        if (!value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or with Guava:

```
return !Booleans.contains(values, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try a foreach loop

```
boolean answerSoFar = true;
for(boolean value : values){
   answerSoFar = answerSoFar && value;
}
return answerSoFar;
```

(NB @shmosel got the following first)
Since the AND condition is used for all the boolean values within the array, you could also return false whenever the false is found within the array; i.e.:

```
for(boolean value : values){
    if(!value){
      return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+, you could use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) like

```
if (IntStream.range(0, values.length).allMatch(i -> values[i])) {
    // all of values are true
}
```

Comment: Isn't it annoying that you can't do `values::[]`?

Comment: @shmosel It is. Not even playing with `Array`, best I could do there was `i -> Array.getBoolean(values, i)`

Comment: Or Guava's `Booleans.asList(values)::get`. Still pretty bloated.

Comment: @shmosel `i -> values[i]` really isn't that bloated. And they might add some kind of syntatical sugar for array access in the future... of course, as it took until Java 8 to get lambdas, I don't think I'll hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

I am C# developer but I know you can use Stream in Java 8 to achieve it. Something like:

```
boolean [] values = new boolean[] { false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false };
Stream<Boolean> stream = IntStream.range(0, values.length).mapToObj(idx -> values[idx]); 
boolean test = stream.allMatch(i -> i);
```

Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have one false in your array, then the result of && is false.

Knowing that, you just need to go through your array and check for false. If you find one, return false. If you don't return true. See shmosel answer for the code.